# How to access Skype with a Microsoft account under Linux

Tags: linux, login, skype, microsoft-account

I'm using Skype for Linux (version 4.2.0.11) and I can't access with my merged Microsoft account.
When I insert my login info I get an error message, *"Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again"*.

By using my standard Skype account it correctly logs in, but obviously this way I can't get my former MSN contacts.

How can I correctly login into Skype?

Comment: Though in my case both Microsoft Account and Skype account result in the same error. I can log through a Skype website.

Comment: Skype account is integrated with the Microsoft Account, so sign-in into your Skype account should have worked. Questions: (1) Do you mean that in your case the two accounts are not integrated? (2) Did you sometime change your email address? (3) Which Linux version? (4) Did Skype ever work before on Linux for you (if so what changed)? (5) Is it possible that you have more than one Microsoft account (Outlook.com, Hotmail, Office 365, OneDrive, Xbox, or Windows)? (6) Try to Sign out of Skype and sign back in. (7) Do you see the contacts on another device?

Comment: @harrymc Thanks! (1) I tried also creating brand new Skype login, brand new Microsoft throwaway accounts (2) On old - maybe, on new not (3) Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (4) Never tried, or tried in distant past (I used it, but IIRC on Windows) (5) I have multiple ones, 3 throwaway ones were created just to debug this (6) I never managed to log in (7) I have no contacts on Skype account

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny: It's quite confusing when poster and bounty are not the same. It would be better if you added a "Bounty" section to the post with as much details as possible. Let me know and I will approve it.

Comment: @harrymc added info

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny: Which is your Linux version? I note that the poster says on his answer that with Skype for Linux version 8.54 he has no more problems.

Comment: This is not a forum, if you have an issue you should open a new question, not arbitrarily modify existing ones with info and specs which are totally unrelated to the original problem. Can you please revert the question to its previous state and open a new one with your specific issue?

Comment: @Sekhemty In my experience on SE it is extremely common to get "duplicate, closed" even for things that are not duplicates at all. This was my attempt to avoid this problem. Sorry for causing a new problem instead.

Comment: @harrymc Skype 4.3, installed from system package. Given that it seems extremely outdated I will try to upgrade to more recent one.

Comment: @Sekhemty: Putting a bounty on an existing post is pretty common here and is allowed by forum rules. In any case, Mateusz Konieczny cannot go back, because his bounty will not be refunded and he doesn't have enough reputation to post another. I suggest that helping him in his problem will only improve the value of your post and bring it up to date.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny: [This link](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-skype-on-ubuntu-18-04/) might help.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny: Very good, so I added an answer with the main points of the article. Better hurry.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the problem, open your Skype configuration folder, usually it's `/home/{your_home_folder}/.Skype/` and delete the `shared.xml` file found here.
After restarting Skype, it will be possible to login with Microsoft account.

Comment: I had to unaccept my own answer, sometimes it seems to work, other times I still am unable to connect. This seem to imply that this is not the true solution to the problem. If you can, please share your knowledge about this.

Comment: This question is from five years ago, and current Skype for Linux version is 8.54. All of this no longer applies, I have nothing more to add, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Using the latest version of Skype will increase the chances of success for
Skype working using a Microsoft account.

Detailed instructions for installing Skype can be found in the article
[How to Install Skype on Ubuntu 18.04](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-skype-on-ubuntu-18-04/).

This is a summary of the commands described in the article:

```
wget https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb
sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb
skypeforlinux
```

Note that this adds Skype to the autostart, you may want to undo this change.